# What is the ettiquite for releasing a Perl module based on someone else's module?

Tags: open-source, code-reuse, credits

I have written a [Perl module](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/dist-zilla-plugin-readmefrompod/tree/anyformat) by starting with an existing Perl module of related functionality and modifying heavily. In fact, acccording to [git blame](https://github.com/DarwinAwardWinner/dist-zilla-plugin-readmefrompod/blame/anyformat/lib/Dist/Zilla/Plugin/ReadmeAnyFromPod.pm) I have changed (or created) every line of non-biolerplate code in the module. Of course, I have also changed the name of the module, so if I uploaded it to CPAN, it would not directly conflict with the original module.

Anyway, despite my heavy modifications, the module is still conceptually based on its predecessor, and I would like to give credit to its authors. However, I can see how they might not appreciate having their names and emails slapped on what appears to be a new module without their knowing. So should I just put myself as the sole author and put the original module's authors in an "Acknowledgements" section? What is the best way to credit the original authors in my module?

Comment: Please retag as appropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about you email the author and ask them how they want to be acknowledge? The seems like the logical thing to do. Don't Perl modules include the email address of the author?

Comment: This is probably the best solution. I was just wondering if there was a standard practice.

Answer (score 0):

Since you based your work on his work, chances are you have no choice but to acknowledge him in the copyright notice. (Depending on the open source license he choosed)